# View moved but still on the top left corner

Tags: android, view, android-layout

I'm adding a custom View to the parent layout, witch is a RelativeLayout.

I also need to move this View on the screen so I do:

```
myView.layout(xx, yy, width, height);
```

This works. The view is moved each time I call this.

The Problem is that when this view is moved,
a copy of it keeps hanging on the top left corner of the layout,
like this:

[image]

Why this happens and how can I prevent this?

Thank you

---

-- Edit --

Some code below.

In the constructor of my custom View:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.ipmaps_lib_balloon_overlay, this);
```

I then add this View to its parent:

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parentLayout.addView(myView, params);
```

When I need to move the View I just do:

```
myView.layout(startX, startY, width, height);
myView.invalidate
```

Comment: first of all! make sure that the view that is still there (the one that should move) is still clickable! and tell me if it is please

Comment: No, the image that is kept in the corner, isn't clickable. Tkanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for this strange behaviour.
It was my fault.

Whenever I changed the position of this message balloon,
I was as well calling `view.draw(canvas)`,
and for this reason, the view was being drawn twice.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), the `layout` method should be used in the `onLayout` phase of the view placement in a viewgroup. If you want to move the view temporarily to another location, use `offsetLeftAndRight(int offset)` and `offsetTopAndBottom(int offset).` 


If that does not help, you will have to `setLayoutParams` for the view.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to request a drawing pass. Call invalidate() on your `myView`.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that but I'm already calling 'invalidate()' right after the 'layout(...)' call. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TranslateAnimation to move your view. and if you have `setFillAfterEnabled(true);` then it will stay where ever you translate it to once it gets there.

Answer (score 1):

Using exact locations with `RelativeLayout` looks like a dirty hack. I think you should use `AbsoluteLayout` instead. It's deprecated but it's used in some Android apps (e.g. `Browser`), so I don't think it will be removed. But if you don't want to use deprecated classes, you can just copy its sources into your project.